# Save state of the button even when navigating through activities

Tags: java, android

So i have a button in a fragment where after clicking it i am disabling it through code and when i go to another activity and come back the button is back enabled again ,i want it to be disabled even if we close the app or navigate other activities.Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Simply used a Shared Preference in your application.Here are the steps you can do it right away to fix problem:

1. Design a class for SharedPreference aka. Preference Manager.

   - Write a boolean method that accept flag(true or false).
2. Call this PreferenceManager on respected Activity or Fragment.
3. On **Button Click** add flag to shared preference and add check to that button for coming flag.
4. Maintain flag properly for first initialization before click because you need to set default flag.
   **If it is true then make button disabled and if not enabled**

Here is the reference site for you
https://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/